# Removing Toolbar from the app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to remove toolbar from the app in `XML` file, look red box in the **image**.

[image]

**The code for that is:**

```
<include  layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

I removed the above code, while running the app it get crash. Why so and how to remove that toolbar in my file?

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dlMain"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context="com.namarsaham.society.jainvidhya.WebViewActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dllayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include  layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

            <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My theme Code:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: what is crash after removing the code, probably you are finding toolbar in your java file.

Comment: Post logcat error.

Comment: The app gets automatically close...

Comment: post your logcat and activity java code

Comment: @PBMusics don't you want to display the title and navigation button?

Comment: Please share your crash log please

Comment: @JyotiJK Yes I dont want the title and navigation button too

Comment: try toolbar.setVisiblity(View.GONE) is or getSupportActionBar().hide()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply add this line **android:visibility="gone"**

```
 <include  layout="@layout/toolbar"
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:visibility="gone"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to hide Title Bar in java file

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**OR**

you can set app theme like below :-

```
<application

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**OR**

You can also try below **in the manifest.xml file**:

**For app:**

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

**For particular activity:**

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: using style which I have recent edited  you have no need to hide and remove actionbar

Comment: this theme how your app without actionbar - toolbar

Comment: I have added the theme code in the question, request you to please confirm and edit with your answer

Comment: can you try with replace your app theme with my edited app theme?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the auto generated Activity, it has a line of code in onCreate

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

if you have removed toolbar from the xml, then using it subsequently will be an issue and cause it to crash (toolbar will be null).

It might be because of this. you can try removing all codes related to toolbar in the activity file, or better yet, just hide/setInvisible the toolbar. It satisfy your requirements to not show the toolbar and  you don't have to worry about it crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your **Activity/Fragment:**

```
View toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

if(toolbar != null){
  toolbar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
}
```